# Printing the second elements of an unordered map that is a set

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a simple question if I have `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<std::string> > h;` how would I print out the second elements of that set h?

I know for the first elements we can just say

```
for (auto it : h) {
    std::cout << "First: " << it.first << " ";
}
```

Although the same does not apply for `it.second`.

```
Error: error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty2' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: What does not let you to iterate over elements of it.second and cout those?

Comment: @ÖöTiib It does not work. Here I will provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate and print the set elements.

```
for (auto& level1 : h) {
    std::cout << "First: " << level1.first << " Second:";
    for (auto& set_element : level1.second) {
        std::cout << set_element << " ";
    }
}
```

If you really want to use `level1.second`, overload << operator

```
ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const std::set<std::string> &myset) 
{ 
    for (auto& set_element : myset) {
        out << set_element << " ";
    }
    return out; 
}
```

and use

```
for (auto& level1 : h) {
    std::cout << "First: " << level1.first << " Second:"<<level1.second;
}
```

Comment: consider using `auto&` instead of plain `auto` to avoid making potentially expensive copies of entire `std::set<std::string>`s

Answer (score 0):

`first` is a string, so you can print it. `second` is a `set` of strings. You can't just cout the set, you have to print a string *inside* the set.

i.e. `it->second.begin()` should give you the iterator to the first element of the set.